# Obtaining the wav file from ServletInputStream

Tags: java, audio

Our current project requires us to send an audio file to the server and then use the audio file for further computation.

Using the Java sound api, I was able to capture the recording and save it as a wav file in my system. Then in order to pass the audio wav to the server, I am using Apache Commons HttpClient to post a request to the server. (I am using InputstreamEntity provided by apache and sending the data as a chunk).

The problem appears when i am trying to recreate/retrieve the wav file on the server. I understand that I would have to use the AudioSystem.write API to create the wav file (exactly as what was done on my system). However what I observe is that althought the file gets created , it does not play (I am using vlc media player to test it FYI). I have searched in Google for sample codes and have tried to implement it, but is unable to play it once the file gets created.

The sample code snippets indicates the approaches i have tried:

```
//******************************************************************

try {
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("output123.wav");
byte[] tempbuffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead=is.read(tempbuffer))!=-1)
{
fs.write(tempbuffer, 0,bytesRead);
}
is.close();
fs.close();
AudioInputStream inputStream =AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(newFile("output123.wav"));
int numofbytes = inputStream.available();           
byte[] buffer = new byte[numofbytes];
inputStream.read(buffer);
int bytesWritten = AudioSystem.write(inputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,new File("outputtest.wav"));
System.out.println("written"+bytesWritten);
```

Approach 2

```
InputStream is = request.getInputStream(); 
System.out.println("inputStream obtained : "+is.toString());
ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
byte[] audioBuffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
System.out.println(" is audioBuffer empty? : length =  ? "+audioBuffer.length);
try {
AudioFileFormat ai = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(is);
System.out.println("ai bytelength ? "+ai.getByteLength());
System.out.println("ai frame length = "+ai.getFrameLength());
Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>> audioProperties = ai.getFormat().properties().entrySet();
System.out.println("entry set is empty ? "+audioProperties.isEmpty());          
for(Map.Entry me : audioProperties){
System.out.println("key = "+me.getKey());
System.out.println("value ="+me.getValue());}       
bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioBuffer);
AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(bais, new AudioFormat(8000,8,2,true,true), 2);
AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,new File("testtest.wav"));

//*************************************************************************************
```

The `audioFormat` properties all turned out to be null. Are these null values giving the problem? So while creating the wave file on the server, I tried to set the properties manually once again. But even then the wav file would not play.

I have also tried quite a few approaches already mentioned on this site, but somehow they aren't working. I am sure i am missing something, but I am unable to pinpoint the exact problem.

Would be really helpful, if you guys can point out how to go about the conversion from ServletInputStream to getting a wav.

P.S (1) I know the code is shabby, because i have been under a trial and error situation for quite some time now. But I will give more details on the approaches if needed.
 2) Apologise for the clumsiness, this happens to be my first post.. )

Answer (score 0):

this is not how you copy a stream (from Approach 1).  you have the correct code to copy a stream just above this.:

```
int numofbytes = inputStream.available();           
byte[] buffer = new byte[numofbytes];
inputStream.read(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, But my problem is , i need to create a wav file in the server using these stream of bytes. Although the file gets created, it doesnt play. i guess that to create the wav i would have to use either an AudioSystem.write or an equivalent api. Can i simply write the bytes to a file and name it with a .wav extension.. i dont think that would work. It would be of gr8 help if u guys can help me out with a pseudo code..

Comment: @user902423 - why do you think my answer is not relevant to what you are trying to accomplish?  if you can't copy the stream correctly, it will be useless to you.

Answer (score 0):

If all your server wants to do is get the data and write it to a file, then you **do not** need to use any of the audio API: simply treat the data as a stream of bytes.

So the part of approach 1 that is before any mention of `AudioInputStream` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Although the approach chosen might not be the perfect solution, due to time constraints, I adopted a simpler approach. Using java.util.zip i simply zipped it up and sent it over to the server and then wrote a layer wherin the file gets unzipped . then i deleted the zip files. Seems like an immature solution (bcos the original challenge was to send the audio file). now i am incurring an overhead of zipping the files, but the file transfer would hapeen relatively faster. Thanks for your help guys.